# Why $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{\frac{(4k+1)\pi}4}^{\frac{(4k+3)\pi}4}\frac{dx}x\ge\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\pi}2\times\frac{4}{(4k+3)\pi}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, summation

This is a step of an answer that I don't completely understand:$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{\frac{(4k+1)\pi}4}^{\frac{(4k+3)\pi}4}\frac{dx}x\ge\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\pi}2\times\frac{4}{(4k+3)\pi}$$

I know that for $x\in[\frac{(4k+1)\pi}4,\frac{(4k+3)\pi}4]$ where $k\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, we have $\frac1x\ge\frac{4}{(4k+3)\pi}$. but I don't understand how it multiplied the fraction by $\frac{\pi}2$ and eliminate the integral on the right hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \mapsto 1/x$ is decreasing on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ therefore,

$$\forall x \in \left[\frac{(4k+1)\pi}4,\frac{(4k+3)\pi}4 \right], \quad x\leq \dfrac{(4k+3)\pi}{4} \quad \text{so}\quad\dfrac{1}{x} \geq \dfrac{4}{(4k+3)\pi}$$

Hence,

$$\int_{\frac{(4k+1)\pi}4}^{\frac{(4k+3)\pi}4}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x \geq\int_{\frac{(4k+1)\pi}4}^{\frac{(4k+3)\pi}4} \dfrac{4}{(4k+3)\pi} \mathrm{d}x = \dfrac{4}{(4k+3)\pi}\left( \dfrac{(4k+3)\pi}{4}-\dfrac{(4k+1)\pi}{4}\right)$$

Therefore,

$$\int_{\frac{(4k+1)\pi}4}^{\frac{(4k+3)\pi}4}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}x\geq \dfrac{\pi}{2}  \dfrac{4}{(4k+3)\pi}$$

Answer (score 2):

Use the inequality, $\ln x \leq x - 1 \implies \ln x \geq 1 - \frac{1}{x}$.

So, $ \displaystyle I = \int_a^b  \frac{1}{x} \ dx = \ln \left(\frac{b}{a}\right) \geq \frac{b-a}{b} $

In this case,

$ \displaystyle  b = \frac {(4k+3) \pi}{4}, \ a =  \frac {(4k+1) \pi}{4}$

So, $ \displaystyle I \geq \frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{4}{(4k+3) \pi} $